# Why was my spam flag on this question about Shopify declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam, moderation

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67349257/8384089) as spam.  Here's the content, in case it's deleted:

> ### Is there any way to use multiple discounts on Shopify and how to apply coupon on cart page. So, that i can retain my customers?
>
> How to use multiple discounts codes? How to use two discount codes on
> cart page? How to retain my customer by giving the discounts?
> [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack)[shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopify)[discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discount)

This is the answer:

[image]

The accounts who are the OP of the question and answer were created today, so it's obviously the same person who answered.

[image: Flag history]

Why was this declined?

Comment: Because the question, when viewed on it's own, is most certainly *not* spam. Simple. The answer appears to be possible spam, but not the question. The question is off topic (it's not about programming) and low quality.

Comment: Also if you think that the answerer is the same person, then you should be raising a custom mod flag.

Comment: @Larnu The question is spam; it's obviously off-topic and and a promotion.  And I didn't raise a custom flag because I already flagged as spam.

Comment: What is the question itself promoting?

Comment: @Larnu Shopify.

Comment: How is it promoting shopify? It's asking how to use shopify, not promoting it... By that train of thought a question about how to use SQL Server is promoting SQL Server, or a question about using Visual Studio on a Mac is promoting Visual Studio and Macs...

Comment: @Larnu It's not asking a programming question, it's asking how to give customers discounts on Shopify.

Comment: And what about that is **advertising** Shopify? An advertisment would be something like "Shopify is a ** product, that provides great services such as ***. Ypu can read about here \[here\](somelink). I'm having trouble with discounts, how would I implement these?"

Comment: @Larnu It's off-topic, and asking how to do something on Shopify; that makes users go to Shopify.  It can't possibly serve another purpose.

Comment: The Q&A is not promoting Shopify, it's promoting KartDiscount, a Shopify *app*.

Comment: Off Topic <> Spam @Anonymous-ReinstatetheCafé , they are completely different things. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375138/how-to-sort-by-dates-excel) for example is very similar, it's not about programming at all. Are you saying it advertising Excel..?

Comment: @Larnu No, it serves a purpose and is an actual question.  This can't serve an actual purpose.

Comment: And the OP is asking about Shopify... @Anonymous-ReinstatetheCafé . The **answer** is advertising. You should have flagged the answer, *not* the question. When you flagged the question *only* the question would have been reviewed **nothing** else. The mod that reviewed it would not have seen the answer in the review queue, and would have seen it's not spam. It's off-topic, yes, but that does not make it spam on it's own.

Comment: I don't know. Looks like spam seed and spam to me. Both users are completely new and are asking and answering something that has nothing to do with programming. Textbook spam seed behavior.

Comment: @Yatin this is called [astroturfing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8323/165773), "advertising, or public relations campaigns seeking to create the impression of being spontaneous "grassroots" behavior..."

Comment: Another time, please don't copy the actual text from spam into your question here. Doing so just does the spammer's job for them by providing another post that is *effectively* spam for that product/company. Please use an image of the post instead. Obviously, if your question is about the actual text, then you may need to copy some of the text, but that wasn't the case here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67349257/3773011) was not spam, nor a spam seed, **at the time you flagged**, nor **at the time your spam flag was handled.**

| Timestamp | Action |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 17:48:39Z | You flagged the question as spam. |
| 2021-05-01 17:50:22Z | I declined your spam flag, as the question itself, with no answer and no history by the OP of spam (I *did* check both), was not spam. The question was also not wildly off-topic, which would have made the likelihood of it being a spam seed substantially higher. |
| 2021-05-01 17:56:59Z | The spam answer was posted, which also clearly indicated the question is a spam seed. |

Basically, you flagged a possibly innocent question as spam. It was neither spam nor a spam seed at the time you flagged, nor at the time your flag was handled. The user had no history of spamming or posting a spam seed. While the question did look a lot like it might be a spam seed, it was not spam nor a spam seed until the answer was posted, which was 8 minutes after you flagged and 6 minutes after your flag was handled.

While I understand the desire to get spam seeds gone quickly, it is inappropriate to flag a question you think may be a spam seed as spam without more evidence that it actually is a spam seed. There are a variety of things which could be sufficient evidence. For example:

- A spam answer posted (on a question that looks a lot like a spam seed). Ideally there would be some connection between the question OP and the answer OP, or the question and answer, but finding such connections is primarily a task for moderators, so it's not expected that you find such.
- A history of spam or spam seed question(s) posted by the user on Stack Overflow, or on other profiles for the network account (a custom flag would be better to direct us to the evidence which is not on SO).
- It's substantially off-topic (e.g. "What's the best CBD oil?", "Who are the best plumbers in X?", etc.).
- Wording in the question which clearly indicates it's definitely looking for a specific company/product/etc. (i.e. the question is *clearly* set up to be answered by specific spam). A history of spam for what it's looking for also helps make it more obvious.
- Something else indicating the intent is that the question be a spam seed.

In general, we should be assuming good faith. To overwhelm that assumption requires a bit more evidence than existed at the time you flagged or at the time your flag was handled.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. The question wasn't spam seed until the answer got posted. And hence the flag was declined. After the answer was posted, all doubt was gone and it could be nuked. Makes sense .

Comment: spammers are subtle in their spam seeds. They know we assume good faith and leverage it.

Answer (score 11):

The question, on its own, is **not** spam. It is most certainly off-topic, and should (probably) be downvoted, voted to close/flagged as off-topic, but it is *not* spam on its own.

The answer, however, is most certainly spam. It *is* advertising a specific Shopify app and it's purely worded to advertise that product. You should have flagged the answer as spam *not* the question.

When you flag a post as spam the moderators will review that item in solitude; they probably don't see the comments and definitely don't see the answers to the question. As such, to a moderator that reviewed your flag, they would have seen an off-topic question, not a spam question.

Likely, as well as the spam flag on the answer you should have raised a custom moderator flag on the question noting that the question itself seems to appear to be a "seed". As there are 2 users involved this would mean that a moderator would review this and if the 2 users are indeed the same, further action could be taken against both.

---

TL;DR: The post as a whole is spam, but not the question itself when reviewed in solitude without the answer. The answer and question together were clearly spam though, and a custom moderator flag would be the far better action here as the spam flag on the **question** would not highlight the true problem to the moderator.

Answer (score 10):

This question was created for the sole purpose of giving the answer, which is really the spam in this case, a question to answer. (As Yatin says, it's a [spam seed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256709/what-is-a-spam-seed).) While it technically doesn't fit the definition of spam, I'm not actually sure if the spam flag should've been accepted, but it would've been better to use the spam flag on the answer, and use a custom flag on either the Q or the A to let us know you suspect this user of sockpuppeting.

I would act on this user, but SpamRam seems to have beaten me to it.

Comment: actually Makyen used Sam "destroy spammer" moderator script on the spammer. Convenient and efficient.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How's that different from just deleting the account?

Comment: @Anonymous-ReinstatetheCafé In our vernacular, "destroying a spammer" usually means a multi-step process which first suspends the profile (the "account" on Stack Overflow, but is actually a "profile" for their Stack Exchange Network account) for 365 days (the maximum length of time for which a moderator can suspend a profile), and then "destroys" the profile, which deletes the profile and deletes all content the spammer had created: questions, answers, comments. If there are any spam posts, those should first be spam-flag deleted, so they're locked and hidden.

Comment: one problem though: answers deleted that way don't get the "spam" flag. I had to go through all those answers manually to re-flag them as spam. Doesn't matter for questions, though.